# Figure out annotated class in ConstraintValidator implementaiton

Tags: java, bean-validation

I need to figure out the annotated class in my custom ConstraintValidator but I didn't find a way without using provider specific API like:

```
ConstraintValidatorContextImpl x = (ConstraintValidatorContextImpl)constraintContext;
getValidationContext().getCurrentOwner();
```

Is there a non provider specific approach to figure out the annotated class?

Thanks a lot for your support.
Oli

Comment: What is the problem you actually need to solve? Based on that it may be possible to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: I have to validate the value depending on the annotated class. There are two types of objects in the application whose set of values (list of protocols) are related but not the same. Therefore, I have to check the value against two distinct lists.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I'd recommend to either implement two separate constraints, one for each target class (they could share implementation code using a delegate or super-class).

Or you implement a class-level constraint, which naturally has access to the validated class and all its properties. Note that you can still let the resulting constraint validation point to a specific property of the class using the constraint builder API in your validator implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to Implement 2 ConstraintValidators, one for each class. The would both use the same Annotation which references them in the validateBy() method.